# Trying to reinstall OS X on a linux drive

Tags: macos, unix

I have decided I don't want to deal with the bugs of linux and would like to go back to OS X. Sadly no matter what I do I cannot seem to get OS X to read the file system that linux uses. I tried formatting it but could not get it to work. After loads of googling I ave up and decided I would ask here.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you asking? Where is the linux volume? Did you format this volume? If so, what format did you use? You appear to have formatted a linux volume and now are trying to read the files? If so, the files are gone.

Comment: Like I said I tried formatting it and partitioning it but no matter what I did OS X refused to read the hard drive. It won't even show up in disk utility

Comment: Volumes are stored in partitions. Changing partitioning can destroy volumes. Formatting a partition creates a new volume with no files. All previous files will be removed. At this point are you just trying to reuse the drive?

Comment: Yes I am. I just wanna reinstall OS X.

Comment: Check out [Apple's Support Article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) first, if you continue to have issues, please modify your question accordingly. You'll want to follow the directions under **Or install from macOS Recovery**

Comment: What type of internal drive do you have? Is the drive a HDD or SSD? Or, do you have a Fusion drive?

Comment: I am using a HDD.

Comment: Not all partition types and filesystems are bootable for MacOS on your machine (the firmware might matter).   The install disk won't repartition or format your HD unless you manually select (from the startup/install disk) menu item disk utility.   The installer won't install on a non-bootable type of filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your internal drive is **not** a Fusion drive, the following Terminal application command should setup your internal drive for an installation of macOS. You will need to run this command from macOS Internet Recovery. Or, if you are booted from an external drive.

```
diskutil  partitionDisk  disk0  1  GPT  JHFS+  "Macintosh HD"  R
```